# String value not converting to date format

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, nsdate

String value not converting to date format. see my code below...

```
    { 
NSString * TempDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@",Datelbl.text,yearString,TimeLbl.text]; // result is Thursday, November 21 2013 3:05 PM

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat : [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"EEEE, MMMM d yyyy hh:mm a" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]];

        AppointmentDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:TempDate];// in .h file  NSDate *AppointmentDate;

    }
```

My problem is appointmentDate displaying nil value?? why ? whats my mistake!!!

Comment: One thing I notice is `hh` when you only have 3:05 instead of 03:05

Comment: Can you paste those values ?

Comment: already posted tempDate value in 1 st line. and, appointmentDate value is nil.!!

Comment: Can you give upvote if u feel this question is useful!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this format:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat :@"EEEE',' MMMM d yyyy hh:mm a"];
```

You need to escape the character that is not part of the format (the comma).

I tried and it works now:

```
NSString *date = @"Thursday, November 21 2013 3:05 PM";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat :@"EEEE',' MMMM d yyyy hh:mm a"];

NSDate *AppointmentDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:date];
```

If your locale is not english, add this:

```
NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:usLocale];
```

Comment: seems that you have added one extra `]`

Comment: Good spot!  Even the Unicode page has an example of not escaping a comma.  That's confusing.

Comment: This will depend on the user's locale setting though.  If it is set to Japanese, for example, I doubt it will recognize Thursday or November.

Comment: I am checking from India... it is giving Null

Comment: It's not, it works, and if your locale is not english, I edited how to edit the locale

Comment: @AntonioMG, still it returns nil value. I'm from india

Comment: I changed my locale to India and it works, are you sure you are using exactly my code and the string looks exactly like that?

Comment: @AntonioMG, if u can , send me a link which explain all dateformats. confused about hh vs HH, yyyy vs YYYY like this

Comment: This is the one I usually use: http://waracle.net/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/

Answer (score 0):

Only this one work for you:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat : @"EEEE, MMMM d yyyy hh:mm a"];
```

Comment: appointmentDate returns this value ... 2013-11-21 10:20:00 +0000

Comment: @Ramdy: This is happening because of timezone, and locale. You can set it if you want to get the same time as per string.

Answer (score 0):

formation of `NSDateFormatter` should be

```
"EEEE, MMMM dd yyyy hh:mm a"  it must match to your date string.
```