# nslocale issue in convert string to date

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm new to xcode, pls see below code and link
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20117861/string-value-not-converting-to-date-format)

```
{
NSString * TempDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@",Datelbl.text,yearString,TimeLbl.text]; //Thursday, November 21 2013 5:35 PM

[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat :@"EEEE',' MMMM d yyyy hh:mm a"];
AppointmentDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:TempDate];    //NSDate 
Appointment = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:AppointmentDate]; //NSString 
}
```

Here , appointmentDate returns this value -> 2013-11-21 12:05:00 +0000,
Appointment returns this value-> Thursday, November 21 2013 05:35 PM.

I need to get 2013-11-21 05.35 PM. So,how to manage this GMT issue.

Comment: What does TempDate look like?

Comment: @ramdy: Plz link your previous question with this, that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
NSString *date = @"Thursday, November 21 2013 3:05 PM";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat : @"EEEE, MMMM d yyyy hh:mm a"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
NSDate *AppointmentDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:date];

NSLog(@"DATE--> %@",AppointmentDate);
```

***Output:***

> DAT--> 2013-11-21 15:05:00 +0000

***Note: NSDate will be in 24 hour format. You need to convert it into string is you want as 03:05...***

Comment: But that way you create a "bad" NSDate object.  The timezone should be set to the timezone of the input (or output when creating the string) so that NSDate itself is UTC.

Answer (score -1):

Edit :

```
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat : @"EEEE, MMMM d yyyy hh:mm a"];
```

[String value not converting to date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20117861/string-value-not-converting-to-date-format?lq=1)

Comment: Your format does not match to input format: `Thursday, November 21 2013 5:35 PM`. Also the problem is not in the format but with the timezone